# How to FIX: TypeError [ERR_FEATURE_UNAVAILABLE_ON_PLATFORM]: when using ts-node-dev in start script

Tags: node.js, npm, ts-node, skaffold

I am writing a node.js app using express, docker, and Kubernetes.
node -v is v12.16.3
Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a
Kubernetes using minikube

I created one Service named as auth and when I tried to deploy it using skaffold dev command I am getting below error

```
[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0m
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mUsing ts-node version 8.10.2, typescript version 3.9.5
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mTypeError [ERR_FEATURE_UNAVAILABLE_ON_PLATFORM]: The feature watch recursively is unavailable on the current platform, which is being used to run Node.js
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0m    at Object.watch (fs.js:1441:11)
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0m    at add (/app/node_modules/filewatcher/index.js:74:34)
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0m    at /app/node_modules/filewatcher/index.js:93:5
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0m    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:176:5)
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR! errno 1
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR! auth@1.0.0 start: `ts-node-dev src/index.ts --poll`
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR! Exit status 1
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR!
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR! Failed at the auth@1.0.0 start script.
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0m
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
←[91m[auth-depl-56db74bf85-b2kst auth] ←[0mnpm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-06-05T09_25_50_079Z-debug.log
```

Bwlow is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "auth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts --poll"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "typescript": "^3.9.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.44"
  }
}
```

Docker file

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Below is the skaffold.yaml

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: xxxxxx/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: 'src/**/*.ts'
            dest: .
```

Comment: BTW I am using Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: This might be because https://github.com/whitecolor/ts-node-dev/issues/143 - can you check if you downgrade to node v13 solves it?

Comment: @BalintPato Thanks for your response. I fixed it by editing the package.json file by editing the scripts as  "start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts --poll"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: 
Modify the package.json with value as 
"start": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts --poll"
And use node:lte-alpine in the Dockerfile